# product image is overlayed on the product description

Tags: product, theme, image

Just look here: http://fitzon.store.magecloud.net/hydro-whey-zero-92-biotechusa.html?___store=ita&___from_store=french

it seems that the images does not stay in the right position, is out of the div.image and for this reason is overlayed the short description.

Someone knows how to fix?
Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

**jm_megamall/styles.css** Change this

line no :4449

```
.product-view .product-img-box .product-image-zoom img {
  cursor: move;
  left: 0;
  position: unset;
  top: unset;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Line no : 4441

```
.product-view .product-img-box .product-image-zoom {
  height: 100% !important;
  overflow: auto;
  position: unset;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9;
}

<p style="width: 775px; height: 440px;" class="product-image product-image-zoom">
```

remove this inline css.

**Note : before this take backup of this file**